# Android OpenGL ES 1.n, screen size v gltranslatef

Tags: android

I have a 2D, landscape game with a mini-map made of sprites.

If I place the mini-map at this location:

gl.glTranslatef(6.67f, 7.48f, 0f);

it's visible on large screens but not on smaller screens because
the coordinates are too big (I'm guessing).

Is there a formula for calculating glTranslatef coordinates based
on screen size?

The centre of screens that I've tested with (Nexus 7 & Galaxy S
II) seem to be at: 0f, 1f (x,y [landscape]).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The default coordinate system for your geometry is independent of the screen size. If things disappear depending on screen size, your own code is probably specifying a transformation that depends on the screen size somewhere. Or you have an entirely different problem that keeps your code from working on some devices.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response.